# Buggy jQuery form serialize, and inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization, forms

I'm seeing some weird inconsistencies when submitting a form, and submitting a form over ajax with `.serialize()`. Here's a minimal example:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="somewhere">
<select name="thing">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="subaru" selected="selected">Subaru</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" value="val">
<button type="submit" name="thing" value="save" >Click me</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
var $ = jQuery;
$('form').on('submit', function(evt) {
    //evt.preventDefault();
    console.log($('form').serialize());
    console.log($('form').clone().serialize());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When you first go to the page, change the selectbox and text, you'll see in the network console (browser submit), and logging console (jQuery serialized) that the text entered is the same in both methods, but the jQuery result is missing the thing=save.

Furthermore, the `serialize()` is giving completely different results for the select-box, when it `clone()`'s the element - you can see in the console:

```
"thing=mercedes&name=edited" jqform.htm:18
"thing=subaru&name=edited" jqform.htm:19
```

Are these a common type of bug in jQuery? Does jQuery need some forms plugin to realize an exact clone of a form should be created with the same form values?

Comment: clone() just clones as the form was created don't do selection.

Comment: @bansi That's false. It clones the elements as they exist, not as the original markup was written.

Comment: @meagar what do you mean? quote from your answer `Note: For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. ` isn't this what I said?

Comment: You said it "clones as the form was created"; that's not true. It clones the current state of the form, including any new elements, and the *current* value of most types of elements. It *doesn't* copy the state of the form as it was at creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these a common type of bug in jQuery?

This is all documented and correct behavior. You should read the documentation to ensure you're actually using the library correctly, rather than assuming you've found such obvious bugs in a popular and well-tested library.

Serialize will never include your `<button>`. It only includes [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

`clone` will not include the `selected` attribute of the select box. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

> Note: For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements.

Comment: Not including the weird button name, value makes sense as that was weird and nonstandard - but it's really odd that the `.clone()` has such behavior - thanks :)

Comment: Only clicked buttons  get sent to the server during normal form submission. jQuery's serialize doesn't know what, if any, button was clicked, so none are included.

Comment: Is there a workaround for clone not copying the textarea / select states?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to serialize/clone/serialize in the first place. The best answer is probably to not clone the form at all.

Answer (score 0):

Like our friend meagar said clone will not include the selected attribute of the select box. so Why dont you just get a duplicate of the result string from the serialized form?!
you could simply do the following to get to what you wish:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(evt) {
    //evt.preventDefault();
    var fm = $(this).serialize();
    var fn = fm;
    console.log(fm);
    console.log(fn);
});
```

Comment: That's not the point - this is a minimal example, I need to process a *copy* of the form before getting the new values.

Comment: Then the output you are getting already is all correct! it gets you the fresh (unfilled) set of elements of the form as created!

Comment: But the changes aren't copied